# простейший select, но не все так просто(?)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, запрос

```
mysql> describe skin;
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| skinid       | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| skin_name    | varchar(15)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| skin_way     | varchar(32)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| date_skin    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| skin_count   | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| uid_skinfrom | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| skcatid_skin | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Нужно из этой тбл выташить значения, одной строкой, но в ДВУХ колонках:

Нужно получить значение skin_count но для разных skinid. В пример приведу два запроса, которые Нужно объебенить. Знаю что можно использовать перепривязку параметров mysqli_stmt_bind_param(), но можно ли в одной строкой вытащить два значения?

Вот примеры запросов (их нужно объеденить в один, ну, эээ, если такое возможно?):

```
select skin_count from skin where skinid=$_SESSEION['cur_skin'];

select skin_count from skin where skinid=$new_skinid;
```

Хочу получить нечто наподобии

```
+--------------+-----------+
| oldcount     | newcount  |
+--------------+-----------+
| 48           | 25        |
+--------------+-----------+
```

Как такое сделать as`ами или вложенными апросами или еще как-то чем-то?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT MAX(CASE skinid WHEN $_SESSION['cur_skin'] THEN skin_count END) oldcount
     , MAX(CASE skinid WHEN $new_skinid THEN skin_count END) newcount
FROM skin;
```

Answer (score 2):

`select (select skin_count from skin where skinid={$_SESSEION['cur_skin']}) as curskin, (select skin_count from skin where skinid=$new_skinid) as newskin`

Comment: с подзапросами  мне понятнее. ща буду разбираться...

Comment: посмотри ответ Akin'ы - учись на правильном)

Comment: согласен, мой вариант самый топорный )))

Comment: этот вариант для меня вчера был самый понятный, но теперь буду использовать другой. Хочу спросить "что тут ТОПОРНОГО?"  Много подзапросов? Тоесть я в волпросе задал вопрос (хм-м... как то интересно звучит) о том чтобы вместо ДВУХ запросов использовать ОДИН, а в вашем решении получаеться аж ТРИ запроса? В этом топрность?

Comment: да, именно поэтому... ну, точнее, запрос к sql-серверу - один (и это уже лучше двух явных запросов), но под капотом, обращений к таблице будет, скорее всего, два (оптимизатор порой бывает хитёр, но в данном случае я сомневаюсь, что он справится), поэтому вариант не оптимален (третий подзапрос - к таблицам не обращается, поэтому почти не в счёт). фактическая разница по времени исполнения, конечно, зависит от объема данных, и с большой вероятностью будет пренебрежимо мала, но все-же, при прочих равных, лучше сразу делать по фен-шую :)

Comment: спс. я так и предполагал.

Answer (score 2):

Можно еще так:

```
select A.skin_count, B.skin_count
  from skin A, skin B
 where A.skinid=$_SESSEION['cur_skin'] and B.skinid=$new_skinid;
```

Но с ограничениями - оба ID гарантированно должны быть в БД. Если хотя бы одного ID не окажется - то запрос ничего не вернет

Comment: потому что в условии есть AND. это я как-бэ :) понял.

Comment: в общем меня чуть пугают странные точки и as’ы в ваших ответах. Пугают потому что я не пони... МАЛО знаю и понимаю в sql. Но как-то по чут-чут вникаю во все это.

Comment: @root_xPovierennyy А что тут странного. берем два раза таблицу skin, что бы точно понимать из какой таблицы что будет обзываем одну A, другую B. При обращении к полям, с помощью точки, указываем из какой именно из таблиц брать поле

Comment: я хочу купить книгу Грабера (Грубера) Введение в sql. Стоит ли ее  покупать? Читал много отзывов - все пишут что там все отлично объясняется. Может есть какя-то книга получше? И вот что еще!: есть она у меня, НО в электронном формате - НО я очень сиьльно не люблю читать много тектса с монитора (я таким чтением пару лет назад немножко испортил себе глаза :(). Покупать мне бумажную. книгу?

Comment: @root_xPovierennyy Я не знаю какая есть литература по SQL. ничего ни разу не читал. Кроме мануалов на конкретные СУБД. и еще можете тут посмотреть ответы http://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0+SQL ...

Comment: Я вообще ничего не читал :( Мне нужно мнение человека имеющего прямое отношение к sql - потому и спросил. Уже решил. Буду ее покупать (надеюсь цены еще адекватные). ну и канешн уже смотрю инф по ссылке.

Comment: там тоже Грабера вспоминают %: